# Sharing how much one earn with spouse?

Tags: practical-islam, sharia

In indo-pak culture, there is a lot of parenting advice not to share expenses/pay with your wife. What does Islam say about it?

Should one tell his pay to his parents? In my experience my mom is likely to discuss my things with other siblings which then question me on my expense and it get a heated argument, as a parent I cannot tell her not to do this because it will also go into argument but in general parent advice are "Not to share with wife because of taunts, e.g. if one do a lot of saving, the wife might come up an say, why u have so much saving, why cannot we pay x and y and so on"

so what does Islam say about sharing pay & finances with wife.

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, the husband is obligated to provide for his wife and children.

According to the **Holy Qur'an:**

> “Men are the maintainers of
> women because Allah has made
> some of them to excel others
> ”(4:34)

And ***Hadith:***

> “Men are the guardians of
> their families and it
> is the responsibility of
> every guardian to guard
> those who fall under his
> own guardianship.”

> A man is the guardian of
> his family (household) and
> is responsible for his
> subjects; a woman is the
> guardian of her husband's
> home and of his children
> and is responsible for them.

Difference between **Ease** and **Necessity** should be clear:

A husband is only obligated to fulfill his wife and children's necessity like water, food, shelter and education.

Convenience/ease of wife and children is not obligated upon the husband, and can be provided by the wife as well.

I also highly recommend reading [Financial Rights of Women](https://www.islamweb.net/en/article/168457/financial-rights-of-women)

Comment: Reference of Hadith will be given on request

Comment: Text quotes are not code please use the ususl format for quotations.

Comment: Ty for the advice! We do that now onwards. @Medi1Saif